# virtual boxが起動できない

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

Windows10のアップデートがかかった後、Virtual boxが起動できなくなりました。
昨日までは、仮想マシン名を右クリック→起動→ヘッドレス起動で問題なく立ち上がっていたのですが
今日Windows updateを実行したら立ち上がらなくなりました。

試してみたこと：
windowsの更新プログラムを削除して再起動した。
Virtual boxを立ち上げる→仮想マシン→新規で新しく仮想マシンを作成した。

以上のことを試したのですが、Virtual boxを起動させようとすると、
「仮想マシン"ｘｘｘ"のセッションを開けませんでした。」と表示されます。
お分かりの方ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `VBoxHardening.log` はご覧になりましたか？

Comment: 自分もこの前これに遭遇しました。 hardening.log を見てみても、(少なくとも自分では) 解決にいたらなかった事案です。(そして諦めて mac を使いだした) 知見がある人がいたら是非情報共有していただけると助かると思っています。

Answer (score 2):

ぐぐっただけですが
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=85336
2017/Nov/4 の時点でエラーメッセージ

```
The virtual machine '～' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:～\VBoxHardening.log'.
```

が出るようになった場合の対応としては
暫定で Windows Security Update KB4043961 をアンインストールしたら動いたとのこと。

2017/Dec/08 に更新を行って動かなくなったのなら先の記事と同様、直近に公開された Security Update をいくつかアンインストールすると良いのではないでしょうか。

もしそれで動くようなら、恒久対策は VirtualBox ないしは Windows Security Update の更新待ちというところでしょうか。